# How to make a chart in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, draw, shapes

So i've been working on alot of things in php, html and css and now i'm interested in Javascript, so i want to know more about charts in Javascript. I know that there are a big amount of classes that i can use, but i want to know how i can make one. I tried to find something useful tutorial or something like that, but couldn't find one.

So, how can i make something like [this](http://www.carlosag.net/images/chartSample.Png) in JavaScript(how to draw lines and shapes)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [canvas api](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html) or take a look at SVG. Here's a great introduction to them both, and what the strength and weakness of each are: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193983(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg193983%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bin I created for something I've been playing with recently. 
[Graph test bin](http://jsbin.com/dabayaso/1/)

A full explanation of how it works can be found on this [article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=839)

It's pretty straight forward, uses HTML5 Canvas and JS